# OpenFaas vs serverless functions provided by cloud service providers

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-functions, openfaas

why we should openfaas instead of lambda functions in AWS or other serverless functions by cloud service providers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to avoid lock-in to a specific vendor. With Open Faas you can run wherever you want while AWS Lambda is tied to AWS.

Comment: So if I'm sure  to use AWS, does it make sense to use openfaas instead of lambda functions?

Comment: not really ... you'd better go with aws lambda for a better integration with aws services